# Bézier curve approximation of a circular Arc

Tags: geometry, circles, bezier-curve

I would like to know how I can get the coordinates of four control points of a Bézier curve that represents the best approximation of a circular arc, knowing the coordinates of three points of the corresponding circle. I would like at least to know the solution to this problem in the case where two of the known circle points are the two ends of a diameter of the circle.

Comment: Can we assume that the second point is half-way along the circular arc?

Comment: No, it can be any point in the circular arc

Comment: It gets **much** more difficult if the interior point isn't mid-way along the arc. I suggest you begin by figuring out the circle through the three points (i.e. compute its center and radius). Type "circle through three points" into your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 3):

For a unit semi-circle centered at the origin, the points are $(1,0)$, $(1, \tfrac43)$, $(-1, \tfrac43)$, $(-1,0)$. Translate, rotate, and scale as needed.

If the end-points of the diameter are $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$, proceed as follows:

Let $\mathbf{U}$ be a vector obtained by rotating $\vec{\mathbf{P}\mathbf{Q}}$ through 90 degrees. Then the control points are $\mathbf{P}$, $\mathbf{P} + \tfrac23 \mathbf{U}$, $\mathbf{Q} + \tfrac23 \mathbf{U}$, $\mathbf{Q}$.

Pseudocode is as follows

```
Vector A = Q - P;
Vector U = new Vector(-A.Y, A.X);   // Perpendicular to PQ
double s = 2.0/3.0;                 // Scale factor
Vector[] controlPoints = { P, P + s*U, Q + s*U, Q };
```

For general circular arcs, complete details are given in "Good approximation of circles by curvature-continuous Bézier curves", by Tor Dokken, Morten Dæhlen
Tom Lyche, Knut Mørken, Computer Aided Geometric Design Volume 7, Issues 1–4, June 1990, Pages 33-41.

Comment: Thanks for you answer in the case of a semi-circle, I actually made a mistake in my question, I want to know the formula not only for a semi-circle but for any circular arc. I edit my post @bubba

Comment: Thanks, do you have an idea for the general case where the two points are not the ends of the circle's diameter ? @bubba

Comment: $4/3$ is the value that makes the spline also go through $(0,1)$.  If you don't insist on this condition you can do a bit better, e.g. the minimum of $\int_0^1 (x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 - 1)^2 \, dt$ is attained when $4/3$ is replaced by $(172 \, / \, 99)^{1/2}$ which is about $1.3181$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies. Yes, and the value that minimizes $\max\{x^2(t) +y^2(t) -1: 0 \le x \le 1\}$ (which is often more meaningful) is something different again. See paper by Dokken at al. that I referenced.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following ways to find the control points of a cubic Bezier curve for approximating a circular arc with end points $P_0$, $P_1$, radius R and angular span A:

Denoting the control points as $Q_0$, $Q_1$, $Q_2$ and $Q_3$, then

$Q_0=P_0$, 
 $Q_3=P_1$, 
 $Q_1=P_0 + LT_0$ 
 
 $Q_2=P_1 - LT_1$

where $T_0$ and $T_1$ are the unit tangent vector of the circular arc at $P_0$ and $P_1$ and $L = \frac{4R}{3}tan(\frac{A}{4})$.

Please note that above formula will give you a pretty good approximation for the circular arc. But it is not "the best" approximation. We can achieve an even better approximation with more complicated formula for the $L$ value. But for practical purpose, above formula is typically good enough.

Comment: What do you mean by "angular span" ? @fang

Comment: Angular span is the spanning angle of that circular arc. For example, a semicircle has 180 degree of angular span and a full circle has a 360 degree of angular span. Be sure to use radian (not degree) in the computation of tan().

Comment: Since tangents are unit-length, shouldn't the formula for $L$ be multiplied by $R$?

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for catching this. I will revise the formula.

Comment: @fang Could you describe "an even better approximation with more complicated formula for the L value"?

Comment: @IvanBunin: Please refer to the paper by Tor Dokken mentioned by the other post.

Comment: @fang your answer is really helpful. Could you clarify what is a "unit tangent", and how can we take those formulas and get actual (x,y) coordinates?

Comment: The unit tangent vector at P0 is the unit vector that is perpendicular to the vector defined by P0 and circle's center.

Answer (score 1):

(I needed a method that was robust in the limit $r\to \infty$, here's what I came up with based on fang's answer.)

We want to approximate an arc through points $A$ and $B$ with radius $r$.  If instead we have 3 points, we can use the side lengths $a, b, c$ of the triangle formed by the points to calculate $r$:

$$\begin{aligned}
s &= \frac{1}{2}(a + b + c) \\
r &= \frac{a b c}{4 \sqrt{s (s - a) (s - b) (s - c)}}
\end{aligned}$$

Let $C_0 = \frac{1}{2}\left(A + B\right)$ be the midpoint of $A$ and $B$.  Let $C = C_0 + D$ be the control point of the quadratic Bézier curve through the points $A$ and $B$ with its midpoint at the midpoint of the arc (where $D$ is perpendicular to $AB$); then
$$|D| = 2 r \left(1 - \cos\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{|A - B|}{2r}\right)\right)\right)$$
Naively computed this has catastrophic cancellation, so I used series expansion, with $x = |A - B|, y = \frac{x}{r}$:
$$|D| = x y \left(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{64} y^2 + \frac{1}{512} y^4 + \frac{5}{16384}y^6 + \frac{7}{131072} y^8 + O(y^{10})\right)$$
If $y$ is not small enough for the series to converge quickly enough, divide the original arc into smaller pieces and retry.

This quadratic Bézier is not a good approximation of a circular arc.  But if we split the original arc in half (the midpoint of the arc is $C_0 + \frac{1}{2} D$), and then find the quadratic control points $C_A$ and $C_B$ for each half as above, they can be modified to give the control points $Q$ of a cubic Bézier curve for the original arc:

$$\begin{aligned}
Q_0 &= A \\
Q_1 &= A + \frac{4}{3}\left(C_A - A\right) \\
Q_2 &= B + \frac{4}{3}\left(C_B - B\right) \\
Q_3 &= B \\
\end{aligned}$$

Diagram:

[image: construction of Q_1]